# Determining if a Javascript object is a "complex" object or just a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, object

I want to be able to pass either a string literal,

```
'this is a string'
```

or a javascript object,

```
{one: 'this', two: 'is', three: 'a', four: 'string' }
```

as argument to a function, and take different actions depending on whether it's a string or an object. How do I determine which is true?

To be specific, I want to iterate over the properties of an object, and do some parsing if a property is a string, but nest recursively if the property is an object. I've figured out how to use `$.each()` to iterate over the properties of the object, but if I just do this with the string, it treates the string as an array of letters rather than as a single thing. Can I get around this some other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var data = {
    foo: "I'm a string literal",
    bar:  {
       content: "I'm within an object"
    }        
};
```

**jQuery**

```
$.each(data, function(i, element){
    if($.isPlainObject(element){
       // we got an object here
    }
});
```

There are similar methods like `$.isArray()` or `$.isFunction()` within the jQuery lib.

**Native Javascript**

```
for(var element in data){
   if(toString.call(element) === '[object Object]'){
      // we got an object here
   }
}
```

To use the `hack'ish` way with `toString` has the advantage, that you can identify whether it is `really` an object and an `array`. Both, objects and arrays would return `object` by using `typeof element`.

Long story short, you cannot rely on the `typeof` operator to distinguish true `objects` and `arrays`. For that you need the `toString.call()`. If you just need to know whether it is any object or not, `typeof` is just fine.

Comment: To anyone wondering why I marked this answer correct rather than one of those with more votes: In this answer there's a suggestion on how to meet my needs using jQuery, which means I don't have to write (or understand in detail) any implementation to use it. This answer also gives good options for covering functions and arrays.

Answer (score 5):

```
var a = 'this is a string';

console.log(typeof a);   // Displays: "string"

var b = {one: 'this', two: 'is', three: 'a', four: 'string' };

console.log(typeof b);   // Displays: "object"
```

Therefore:

```
if (typeof yourArgument === 'string') {
   // Do the string parsing
}
else if (typeof yourArgument === 'object') {
   // Do the property enumeration
}
else {
   // Throw exception
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Some further considerations:

1. See [@Andy E's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94197/andy-e) comment below.
2. `typeof null` returns `"object"` as well. The same applies to any other object, including arrays.

Comment: +1, because the OP asked specifically about string literals, but remember that `typeof new String("Hello") == "object"`.  To be absolutely certain, use `a.constructor == String`.

Comment: You cannot distinguish between `objects` / `arrays` and `null` with typeof.

Comment: @jAndy: Yes true. I stated that in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
function some_function(argument) {
  if (typeof(argument) == "string" || argument.constructor == String) {
    // it's a string literal
  } else if (argument && typeof(argument) == "object" && argument.constructor != Array) {
    // it's an object and not null
  } else {
    // error
  }
}
```

Thanks to [Andy E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94197/andy-e) for the tipp with `argument.constructor`.

Comment: what's the down vote for? I would appreciate a comment! So I know what I've done wrong.

Comment: @Jens F. I agree. Good answer. A down vote here is utterly useless. Have a +1 from me :-)

Comment: this will fail calling `some_function(null)`, since `typeof(null) === 'object'`.

Comment: @jAndy. you're a little bit late, I've already updated my code.

Comment: @Jens F.: indeed, but still `typeof` does not know wheter it is an array or a true object.

Comment: @jAndy, Thank you, I'm always happy to learn while answering questions!

Answer (score 2):

Try the [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/typeof_Operator) operator. It will return `object` for objects and `string` for strings.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
function something(variableX){
  if (typeof(variableX) === 'object'){
     // Do something
  }else if (typeof(variableX) === 'string'){
     // Do something
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem and I think I figured out a solution. Here is my sample code for anyone who is interested.

```
var propToDotSyntax = function (obj) {
    var parse = function (o, n) {
        var a = [], t;
        for (var p in o) {
            if (o.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                t = o[p];
                if (n !== undefined) tmp = n + '.' + p;
                else tmp = p;
                if (t && typeof(t) === 'object') a.push(arguments.callee(t, tmp));
                else a.push(tmp + '=' + t);
            }
        }
        return a;
    };
    return parse(obj).toString();
}
var i = { prop: 'string', obj: { subprop: 'substring', subobj: { subsubprop: 'subsubstring' } } };

propToDotSyntax(i);
```

This will go through all the properties of an object — even if the properties are objects themselves — and return a string with the following values in dot syntax.

```
"prop=string,obj.subprop=substring,obj.subobj.subsubprop=subsubstring"
```

I got the inspiration from [DavidPirek.com](http://www.davidpirek.com/blog/object-to-string-how-to-deserialize-json) — Thanks Mr. Pirek!